# Distribution of $\frac{(\sin(n))^2}{2^n}$ in dyadic intervals?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, discrepancy-theory

Good morning all,

I was wondering what kind of methods could help in order to tackle the following problem :

1. Define the set $A = \left\{ \frac{(\sin(n))^2}{2^n}\right\}$ for $n$ integer. So A is a discrete set who has 0 as a point of accumulation.
2. For $k$ integer, define also the dyadic interval $I_k = \left[\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} , \frac{1}{2^{k}}\right]$.

**Question :  For any $k$ integer, do we have $$X_k := \#(A \cap I_k) < 5?$$**

Numerically I have checked this for large $k$...

If I may comment ; the problem here is that we do not have control on the $\sin(n)^2$ which may sometime be very small and then send some element of the sequence into a large $I_k$ (and not $I_n$ or $I_{n+1}$ or $I_{n+3}$).

I have put $5$ here because this is a constant that I have checked with computer but anything which is independent of $k$ is fine.

We have trivial bound like  $X_k < k$ but this is not enough..

Do you know what kind of math could do here ? I don't think that diophantine approximation could work here personally (or things like that).

Thanks :)

Comment: p.s. : I have put a_n = sin(n)^2 but of course you can also put  a_n = \pi n [1] or anything which is "natural" and painful (ie which oscillates in (0,1))...

Comment: I suppose it's Diophantine approximation, what else? It's probably very difficult, since it would involve Diophantine approximation properties of pi, which are not well-understood (compare: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06345). As a test case you could instead try sin(n phi pi)^2, where phi is the Golden Mean, and some generalizations of that (the point is that you would need to use Diophantine approximation properties of phi, which are well understood).

Comment: thank for you comment,

however I don't think diophantine approximation will be useful here..

Comment: can you use mathjax for readability of your question?

Comment: yes ! I have changed the typo, didn't know we could use the $ in live !

Comment: @Anthony: Why do you think that diophantine approximation techniques will not be useful here? If $n/m$ is a good approximation for $\pi$, then $n \approx \pi m$, and so $\sin^2 n$ will be very small. Isn't understanding these values precisely the problem?

Comment: hmm I tried a bit into this direction but then I thought it won't be enough.. but maybe you are right I'll try more then.

Comment: I don't know whether $\sin(n)^2$ is supposed to be $(\sin n)^2$ or $\sin(n^2)$. Please edit the body of the question to clarify.

Comment: Hi ! yes i'll edit asap ; it's supposed to be $(\sin(n))^2$ !

Comment: @GerryMyerson : actually I have put $ (\sin(n))^2$ because I wanted to follow the following strategy. First one consider the same problem but with the set $$B = \left\{ \frac{(\cos(n))^2}{2^n} \right\}.$$ The first step is that the set $A$ and $B$ have the same behavior on the dyadic scale. Then step 2 is to exploit the fact that $A+B$ when sum terms by terms is really $\left\{ \frac{1}{2^n} \right\}$ : if both $A$ and $B$ have bad behavior this may lead to a contradiction.

But actually I'm stuck at step 1 already...